# Make bootstrap site fit multiple screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started playing around with bootstrap since I am new to HTML and CSS.

I was looking at this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/).

I started to make something simple on my surface pro but then when I switched to my 24" screen I noticed the text and image spread apart from the center leaving a gap:

[image]

**This is what it should look like:**

[image]

I know when I do the same with the bootstrap example the center of the screen stays the same but the edges widen and spread apart. I know this is a nooby question but whatever. Thanks.

Here is [my code](http://pastebin.com/zmrjb0UW) if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the jumbotron wrap the contents in a `.container` div like:

```
<div class="container">
       ...contents...
</div>
```